# Elasticsearch Completion Suggester field contains comma separated values

Tags: search, lucene.net, nest, elasticsearch

I have a field that contains comma separated values which I want to perform suggestion on.

```
 {
    "description" : "Breakfast,Sandwich,Maker"
 }
```

Is it possible to get only applicable token while performing suggest as you type??
For ex:
When I say `break`, how can I get only `Breakfast` and not get `Breakfast,Sandwich,Maker`?

I have tried using commatokenizer but it seems it does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html), you can provide multiple possible inputs by indexing like this:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/music/song/1?refresh=true' -d '{
    "description" : "Breakfast,Sandwich,Maker",
        "suggest" : {
            "input": [ "Breakfast", "Sandwitch", "Maker" ],
            "output": "Breakfast,Sandwich,Maker"
    }
}'
```

This way, you suggest with any word of the list as input.

Obtaining the corresponding word as suggestion from Elasticsearch is not possible but as a workaround you could use a tokenizer outside Elasticsearch to split the suggested string and choose only the one that has the input as prefix.

EDIT: a better solution would be to use an array instead of comma-separated values, but it doesn't meet your specs... ( look at this: [Elasticsearch autocomplete search on array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789224/elasticsearch-autocomplete-search-on-array-field) )

Comment: As a workaround, is it possible to perform suggest across multiple fields??

Comment: You can use multiple suggesters then, one on each field. If you can modify your specifications, you can also simple make suggestions on an array as shown in my edit (instead of a string with comma-separated values)