# Elasticsearch search suggestion on array field with partial edge ngram completion

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to build a suggester based on arrays of strings in my documents, it is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789224/elasticsearch-autocomplete-search-on-array-field) but with several differences : the `completion suggester` from Elasticsearch is not exactly doing what I want (in terms of filtering and prefix matching), as I need an edge ngram that would work on any word of the sentence, accent-insensitive. Let me clarify with an example.

Assume I have the following indexed documents. I want to suggest "tags" based on a query `q` (I don't care about the document themselves, only the `tag`s that match my query)

```
[
  { "tags": [ "société générale", "consulting" ] },
  { "tags": [ "big data", "big", "data"] },
  { "tags": [ "data" ] },
  { "tags": [ "data engineering" ] }
  { "tags": [ "consulting and management of IT" ] }
]
```

I want to match prefix with accent tolerance, and the following query/responses highlight what I need

- (1) `q = "societe"` or `q = "societe generale"` should return `[ "société générale" ]` --> accent insensitive
- (2) `q = "big data"` should return `[ "big data" ]` --> both prefixes "big" and "data" must be in the string
- (3) `q = "data"` should return `[ "big data", "data", "data engineering" ],` --> anywhere in the sentence (but as a prefix)
- (4) `q = "ata"` should not return anything (not a prefix)
- (5) `q = "IT consulting"` should return `[ "consulting and management of IT" ]` --> both prefixes of `q` should match regardless of order

If I use a regular `completion` mapper+suggester,

```js
# assuming a mapping of "tags", of type 'completion' is configured in my ES
{
  suggest: {
    text: "big data",
    tags: {
      completion: {
        field: "tags",
      },
    },
```

almost none of these cases work apart from (2), (4) and 1/3 results from (3)

Can I build a custom suggester or a custom search query that would satisfy my requirements and the examples given above ?

Comment: did you get a solution to this?

Comment: No. I've heard elasticsearch 7.3 might have some features that could help with this but unfortunately they still haven't released this version on AWS

Comment: you should checkout Opensearch - Documentation. AWS is going to switch to Opensearch in the near future because of license reasons
https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticsearch-service/the-elk-stack/what-is-opensearch/
https://opensearch.org/docs/opensearch/ux/#autocomplete-queries
maybe the will release with the features you are need 

Comment: Not yet. We've paused work on our search engine for quite some time, and haven't upgraded our ES clusters for a while. It's likely that new versions are more flexible and there's even the new vector/semantic search that could provide help with this.